# Xib labels referenced in another viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, ios11, swift4

This is the error message I get:
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.'
The below explains how it differs from the other questions posted. Since I am actually following the instructions from the link provided.

I have linked the Xib as follows:
The ViewController I would like to use is MapViewController. 
The Xib is MarkerInfoView
The file owner is MapViewController and it's also where I have created the outlets.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)

Comment: it's different in the sense that I use the answers provided there. Also this is for XCode 9 and swift not objective C and the older version of Xcode shown there.

Comment: It's difficult to tell much from what you posted, but in my experience this error happens when your outlets are mismatched. Try reviewing each one to make sure they point to a valid outlet and make sure there are no extra outlets, left by maybe changing names or erasing code and not the connection

Comment: happy to add details. But the screen shots were meant to show that the outlets were properly set up, as well as the FileOwner.

Comment: Actually I just realized, the error specifically says there's a problem with your nameLabel outlet. Maybe try unconnecting and reconnecting that outlet?

Comment: Thank you, just tried it again. I deleted the connection and the variable in the code, then recreated it. Same error message.

Comment: Just opened as source code as well and I don't see any problem with potential multiple connections.

Comment: Remove the old outlet from code and from inspector and try making a new one.

Comment: Thx Chaudhry but already tried that...

Comment: Maybe you need to have in your Xib file a ViewController (I'm assuming you only have the View).

Comment: Thx Adi. Already present too.

Answer (score 0):

i think that this happens becouse when you register your xib with a fileowner it maybe recreated and the outlets are disconeccted automaticlly.
i don't use that way of registring nibs

Comment: Thx but I tried adding the outlets again per my discussion with CodeNinja so that doesn’t happen. What’s the other approach you are referring to?

Comment: remove MarkerInfoView from file's owner and add it at View, which is down first responder. that's how i use them, becouse i used to have the same problem

Comment: Thanks enea but I need the xib as it is because it's used as a marker on a map. So it wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Hi Enea, was revisiting this. What did you mean by "add it at View". What is "it"? thanks

Answer (score 0):

For using xibs initialize with `MapInfo(nibName: "XibName", bundle: nil)`

Comment: @user2867432 I just cannot see code on image. It’s too small

Answer (score 0):

Other possible thing is that your outlets actually connected to mapinfoview, not controller. Delete them and recreate onto your viewcontroller

Comment: Hello, Please see the following : "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel."